CodeLite install Ubuntu
Can you show me step by step how to install CodeLite on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS via terminal ?
Which is the last version ,which version should I install?
I have seen there  versions 17.0.0 and 17.10.0..
I installed version 17.9 but it’s crashing ..
I know theres answers already about this but I don’t know If is really up to date.

In Ubuntu 24.04, CodeLite 17 is available in the Universe repository. So
sudo apt install codelite

should just work, or
sudo apt install codelite-plugins

if you want the plugins.
